# the ad size and ad unit id must be set before load is called

Tags: android, android-layout

Q1 I am not able to find a solution.. `logCat` window shows `IllegalStateException -  "the ad size and ad unit id must be set before load is called " error! "`
I have used res-auto and `ad:Size = "BANNER"`

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.androhttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/29409592/editid.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="0dp"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:paddingRight="0dp"
 android:paddingTop="0dp"
 android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <com.example.jatinarora.threestickhockey.mView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/abcde"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id2">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity class onCreate function

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.abcde);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

It will be great help if any one could answer

Comment: <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView and it tag dont close

Comment: dont use relative layout for adview instead use linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.abcde);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Where ur close ' } ' in `onCreate` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Alter your XML something like this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/abcde"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id2"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys but the problem was very trivial !

The banner id was not written correctly

Bad news for me is i got stuck in another problem! 
I will be really thankful if anyone of you could have a look!

[Interstitial Add is not getting loaded in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419498/interstitial-add-is-not-getting-loaded-in-android)

and again sorry for the trouble! :D